# java globle object reference not changing locally

Tags: java

I have a globle flag to enable logging / disable logging and a class level flag as well.

This is the code:

```
public class Utils {
    public static volatile boolean GLOBLE_LOG_FLAG = true;
}

public class TestClass {
    private static volatile Boolean LOCAL_LOG_FLAG = Utils.GLOBLE_LOG_FLAG;

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("LOCAL_LOG_FLAG: = " + LOCAL_LOG_FLAG);

        Utils.GLOBLE_LOG_FLAG = false;

        System.out.println("now LOCAL_LOG_FLAG: = " + LOCAL_LOG_FLAG);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass class1 = new TestClass();
        class1.test();
}

Output:

LOCAL_LOG_FLAG: = true
now LOCAL_LOG_FLAG: = true
```

Why `LOCAL_LOG_FLAG` does not change when i set `Utils.GLOBLE_LOG_FLAG = false;`

If java is using object reference it should change `LOCAL_LOG_FLAG` to false when I assign `Utils.GLOBLE_LOG_FLAG = false;` isn't it ? What's my mistake here?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1

Comment: There are no globals in Java.

Comment: event public static?